# Add a single count column to a groupby Pandas dataframe while getting the means from the quantity columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add **a single count column** to the dataframe when using `dataframe.mean()` or through some other way (results will be scatter plotted).

I can't use `.agg(["count","mean"])` because it adds `count` and `mean` columns for each quantitive metric making the dataframe very large and harder to plot.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    'store':['store_a', 'store_a', 'store_b', 'store_b', 'store_b', 'store_c',],
    'location':['North America', 'North America', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe'],
    'sales':[10, 5, 20, 20, 20, 10],
    'cost':[5, 4, 10, 14, 14, 8],
  }
)
df_grouped = df.groupby(["store", "location"]).mean()
df_grouped
```

Actual:

```
store      location         sales   cost
store_a    North America    7.5     4.5
store_b    Europe           20.0    12.66
store_c    Europe           10.0    8.0
```

Expected:

```
store      location         count   sales   cost
store_a    North America    2       7.5     4.5
store_b    Europe           3       20.0    12.66
store_c    Europe           1       10.0    8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Named aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=filter#named-aggregation) here:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['store','location'], as_index=False)\
    .agg(count=('location','count'), 
         sales=('sales','mean'), 
         cost=('cost','mean'))

print(df_grouped)

     store       location  count  sales       cost
0  store_a  North America      2    7.5   4.500000
1  store_b         Europe      3   20.0  12.666667
2  store_c         Europe      1   10.0   8.000000
```

It doesn't really matter which column you choose for "count" (or indeed "size"), both `store` or `location` will lead to the same column.

---

If you have numerous columns and don't want to add the aggregations manually, you can use a dictionary comprehension. E.g. something like this:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'location']
# ['store', 'sales', 'cost']

df_grouped = df.groupby(["store", "location"], as_index=False).agg(**{
    (col if col != 'store' else 'count'): 
        ((col,'mean') if col != 'store' else (col,'count')) for col in cols})
    
# passing:
    {'count': ('store', 'count'),
     'sales': ('sales', 'mean'),
     'cost': ('cost', 'mean')}

print(df_groupby)

     store       location  count  sales       cost
0  store_a  North America      2    7.5   4.500000
1  store_b         Europe      3   20.0  12.666667
2  store_c         Europe      1   10.0   8.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you need the store count. Use agg

```
df.groupby(['store','location']).agg(**{'sales': ('sales', 'mean'),
                           'cost': ('cost', 'mean'),
                           'count': ('store', 'size') })


   store       location     sales    cost   count
0  store_a  North America    7.5   4.500000      2
1  store_b         Europe   20.0  12.666667      3
2  store_c         Europe   10.0   8.000000      1
```

With your new requests try:

```
df.groupby(['store','location']).agg(**{col: (col, 'count') if col in (['store']) else (col, 'mean') for col in df.drop(columns=['location']).columns }).rename(columns={'store':'count'})
```